# NSSound undeclared on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, nssound

```
sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"staticbeam09.wav" byReference:YES];
```

Code referenced from [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sound/Tasks/LoadingAudioData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000786-BAJFBAAH). Getting an error when I put this in viewDidLoad. If I put

```
NSSound *sound;
```

in the header file, I get the specifier-qualifier error at the top of my implementation file. What do I have to do to make this work? I was just pasting the code from Apple's documentation - has this been deprecated? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/04/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-4-basic-game-audio/

that is how i did the audio bg music and sound effects at the end for iconquer

Comment: Hey, tried that. I'm getting a nil string parameter crash on the second line of this:
 NSString *beamPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"staticbeam09" ofType:@"wav"];
 CFURLRef beamURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:beamPath];

staticbeam09.wave is in my resources folder. tried putting \resources\staticbeam09 and that didn't work.. any idea what parameter it thinks I'm passing as nil?

Comment: I don't have my code infront of me but from a glance it looks like the resource you are using needs to be in caf format, the iPhone doesn't utilize a windows audio codec. Icodeblog includes a terminal command for converting it. Try that and lemme kno

Comment: Oh! I thought .wav was a universal lossless format. It works now! Thanks to everyone who helped out on this. Now I've got sounds working in my game!

Comment: Well, one sound does. I used Itunes to convert to m4a, the other sound I converted and nothing plays, also tried playing an MP3 and I hear no sound.. no errors, and I can play the working sound just fine.. each sound file has their own SystemSoundID etc. Could there be some setting/attribute of the sound file I can check that would give reason for Xcode to not play it? I hope this isn't too vauge.. I'll try other sounds, seems weird one will work and the others won't.

Comment: (and yes each one has their own url / path variable)

Comment: Hm.. even that static sound won't play on my iPod, but it plays in the Simulator. Is there something else I have to do? Thanks again everyone for all of your help!

Comment: In my experience, I have only ever been able to use the .caf format, it may be that that is the only one supported by the framework. I have 3 different .cafs in my game and they all work just fine, if you need anymore I can upload the code as I used it.

Comment: Sorry for the extra comments, my mistake! converted to m4a not realizing I had to change Itunes to get AIFF, then I switched that to .CAF. MP3's still not playing but the .wav to .caf's work, I'll figure out the mp3. Thanks again.

Comment: no prob, i was able to convert mp3 using that command from before (atleast thats what i think it was originally)

Answer (score 6):

There is no NSSound class in iPhone SDK
It's only for MacOS

Answer (score 3):

Oxigen’s right. If you want to play sounds on iPhone, there are several options. Probably the easiest one is using Audio Services ([example wrapper](http://gist.github.com/205857)), then there is [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html) and then you can also use OpenAL (I’ve written a very basic OpenAL sound effect engine called [Finch](http://github.com/zoul/Finch)). Depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Zoul, I tried putting your code in my main implementation file, and in viewDidLoad I put:
 Sound *abc = [[Sound alloc] initWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"staticbeam09.wav"]];
 [abc play];
It compiles fine, but I get an uncaught exception at runtime. Any idea why? Thank you both for your help.

Comment: The `stringWithFormat:` call is not necessary, you can use `@"string"` directly. The code is not exactly what I use, I might have left some bug in there. What exception do you get? Do you have the sound file added in the Resources group in Xcode?

Comment: Oh, I looked at the view report and it said there was an error in loading the sound. Double-checked the names and their fine, double-clicking the file in Resources plays it in Itunes too.

Comment: Sorry, in that case you’ll have to debug the code yourself. Take a look inside the `initWithPath:` method, see what `resourceDir` and `fullPath` expand to and check if the file is really on that path. This has to work, there’s just a tiny mistake somewhere.